# Can Android TV display portrait? (flutter)

Tags: flutter, smart-tv

Is it possible to make an application on Android TV but the display must be portrait according to the size of the TV, using the Flutter programming language

````
Example AndroidManifest.xml

``` 
<activity
   android:name=".MainActivity"
   android:exported="true"
   android:launchMode="singleTop"
   android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
   android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
   android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
   android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```
````

Results:
[image]

Thank you very much

Comment: Do you mean you want to use the TV sideways or something?

Comment: Yes, sideways like the portrait position of a phone

Answer (score 0):

we get the idea of the position we rotate

*Example AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<activity
   android:name=".MainActivity"
   android:exported="true"
   android:launchMode="singleTop"
   android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
   android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
   android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

*Example page.dart*

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: RotatedBox(
        quarterTurns: 3,
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          color: const Color(0xFFE8581C),
          child: const Text('data'),
        ),
      ),
    )
  );
}
```

Results
[image]